# How to get the next page on a website using requests and bs4

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to web scrape the info from a leader board on [this](https://fuelrats.com/leaderboard) website, but it only shows 25 entries at once and the url doesn't change when you press the "next" button to get the next 25 entries. What I want to do is to get all the "number of rescues" from all the entries in the leader board so I can check if the "number of rescues" follows a pareto-distribution (meaning that, for example, the top 20 % of all people are responsible for 80 % of all rescues).

So I can get the first 25 entries no problem like this:

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://fuelrats.com/leaderboard'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

rows = soup.findAll('div',{'class':"rt-tr-group",'role':"rowgroup"})

print(len(rows))
```

but after that, I don't know how to press "next" from python and then get the next 25 entries. How can I do that? Is it even possible with just requests and bs4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way of getting that data, by scraping the API endpoint that page is being hydrated from. The API url can be found in Dev Tools - Network tab, under 'XHR' section.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://fuelrats.com/api/fr/leaderboard?page%5Boffset%5D=0&page%5Blimit%5D=5000')
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['data'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    type    id  attributes.preferredName    attributes.ratNames attributes.joinedAt attributes.rescueCount  attributes.codeRedCount attributes.isDispatch   attributes.isEpic   links.self
0   leaderboard-entries e9520722-02d2-4d69-9dba-c4e3ea727b14    Aleethia    [Aanyath, Aleethia, Konisho, Ravenov]   2015-07-28T00:06:53.000Z    15467   2228    False   False   https://api.fuelrats.com/leaderboard-entries/e...
1   leaderboard-entries 5ed94356-bdcc-4139-9208-3cec320d51c9    Elysiumchains   [Alysianfolly, Elysianfields, Elysiumchains, E...   2018-06-22T00:07:59.000Z    8476    810 True    False   https://api.fuelrats.com/leaderboard-entries/5...
2   leaderboard-entries bb1d04cd-2889-4994-ad6a-3fb881a5d243    Caleb Dume  [Agamedes, Alcamenes, Andocides, Argonides, Ca...   2019-09-14T03:40:37.101Z    3163    309 True    False   https://api.fuelrats.com/leaderboard-entries/b...
3   leaderboard-entries 4a3ebe7a-35e6-4371-94f7-50db34c0167a    Falcon JSDF [Falcon JSDF]   2016-03-01T02:44:51.265Z    2639    210 True    False   https://api.fuelrats.com/leaderboard-entries/4...
4   leaderboard-entries 9257c634-8c79-4d0c-b64c-f9acf1672f3a    JERRYCLARK  [JERRYCLARK]    2017-05-26T15:58:34.000Z    2452    229 False   False   https://api.fuelrats.com/leaderboard-entries/9...
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
3455    leaderboard-entries 55e8f803-9005-4c99-a5c3-d8ea49ac365a    Boonlike    [Boonlike]  2020-11-28T20:52:22.250Z    1   0   False   False   https://api.fuelrats.com/leaderboard-entries/5...
3456    leaderboard-entries 46da00f1-0ac4-475c-9fc9-9da81624a5cd    gamerjackiechan2    [gamerjackiechan2]  2018-06-04T18:51:10.000Z    1   0   False   False   https://api.fuelrats.com/leaderboard-entries/4...
3457    leaderboard-entries e1d78729-3813-451e-95ff-f64c76bce4ba    DutchProjectz   [DutchProjectz] 2015-09-06T02:46:26.000Z    1   0   False   False   https://api.fuelrats.com/leaderboard-entries/e...
3458    leaderboard-entries 57417a4e-b7a9-4612-8d66-59b69b33447e    dalam88 [dalam88]   2017-07-25T14:48:13.000Z    1   0   False   False   https://api.fuelrats.com/leaderboard-entries/5...
3459    leaderboard-entries 233a183a-b270-441f-bd55-258511cd9541    Glyc    [Glyc, Glyca94] 2021-03-22T19:36:24.121Z    1   0   False   False   https://api.fuelrats.com/leaderboard-entries/2...
3460 rows × 10 columns
```

Comment: could you explain what an API endpoint is and how you found that url from which you are scraping?

Comment: @J.Doe, you can read about API endpoints [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/security/api/what-is-api-endpoint/). The API url can be found in browser's dev tools - network tab.